# Binding a Table to a Sub Property

Tags: c#-4.0, data-binding, properties

There are a couple of answers out there for this already, but I have not been able to find anything conclusive.  This is the jist of what I am trying to do:

**EquityInstrument**

```
public class EquityInstrument : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Symbol;
    public string Symbol
    {
        get
        {
            return _Symbol;
        }
        set
        {
            _Symbol = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Symbol");
        }
    }

    public EquityInstrument(string Symbol)
    {
        this.Symbol = Symbol;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string FieldName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(FieldName);
        }
    }
}
```

**OptionInstrument**

```
public class OptionInstrument : INotifyPropertyChanged;
{
    public readonly EquityInstrument UnderlyingInstrument;

    private double _StrikePrice;
    public double StrikePrice
    {
        get
        {
            return _StrikePrice;
        }
        set
        {
            _StrikePrice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StrikePrice");
        }
    }

    private DateTime _Expiration;
    public DateTime Expiration;
    {
        get
        {
            return _Expiration;
        }
        set
        {
            _Expiration = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Expiration");
        }
    }

    public OptionInstrument(string Symbol, double StrikePrice, DateTime Expiration)
    {
        this.Symbol = Symbol;
        this.StrikePrice = StrikePrice;
        this.Expiration = Expiration;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string FieldName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(FieldName);
        }
    }
}
```

This code initiates the Option Table...

```
GridControl OptionGrid = new GridControl();
BindingList<OptionInstrument> BoundList = new BindingList<OptionInstrument>();

public void InitializeDataTable()
{
    OptionGrid.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = BoundList };

    BandedGridColumn Column0 = new BandedGridColumn();
    Column0.FieldName = "Symbol";

    BandedGridColumn Column1 = new BandedGridColumn();
    Column1.FieldName = "StrikePrice";

    BandedGridColumn Column2 = new BandedGridColumn();
    Column2.FieldName = "Expiration";

    BandedGridView MainView = (BandedGridView)OptionGrid.MainView;

    MainView.Columns.Add(Column0);
    MainView.Columns.Add(Column1);
    MainView.Columns.Add(Column2);

    BoundList.Add(new OptionInstrument("DELL", 12.22, new DateTime(2012, 10, 12));
    BoundList.Add(new OptionInstrument("MSFT", 13.23, new DateTime(2012, 09, 16));
    BoundList.Add(new OptionInstrument("SPY", 12.23, new DateTime(2012, 07, 18));
}
```

What do you think?  Are there any good design patterns to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is not clear and your code is incorrect. Your are setting a property Symbol on OptionInstrument, but this type doesn´t have a property Symbol.

Comment: Should link the other answers you're referring to. And what is the problem you're trying to solve?